# Cancel Http handler request

Tags: http, go

I have handlers that respond to https requests. In the handlers I call a function F1() which does some application logic and connects to a mysql db and does a query. I want to know how I can use the golang context package to cancel the Db  query if the client cancels the request. Do I need to pass the ctx to F1()? Also the code I have now will take 4 seconds even if F1() returns in  less then 4. How can I return as soon as F1() returns?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  ctx:= r.context()

  F1()


 select {

     case <-ctx.Done():

     case <- time.After( 4*time.Second):

   }


   w.WriteHeader(http.statusOk)
  return 

 }
```

Comment: "Also the code I have now will take 4 seconds" -- Fix this by getting rid of the explicit delay. What purpose is that meant to serve?

Comment: Also the code you've included won't even compile. It would be nice to use _actual code_ in your question.

Answer (score 3):

To begin, I highly recommend taking a look at the [Context blog post](https://blog.golang.org/context) to familiarize yourself with contexts, in addition to reading over the [`context` documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/context) itself.

To address your specific questions:

**How can you cancel the database query if the user cancels their quest?**

To make this work, there are a few things you want to check:

1. Ensure that your database driver (if you are using `database/sql`) supports context cancellation.
2. Ensure you are using the Context variants of all available methods (e.g. [`db.QueryContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryContext) instead of [`db.Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)).
3. Ensure that you are passing the context (or a derivative of the context) through the stack from your HTTP request through to the database calls.

**Do I need to pass the ctx to F1()?**

Per #3 above, yes: you will need to pass the context through all intermediate calls to "connect" the database call with the request context.

**How can I return as soon as F1() returns?**

The code that you have in your question calls `F1` in series, rather than concurrently, with your cancellation/timeout `select`.

If you want to apply a specific deadline to your database call, use [`context.WithTimeout`](http://golang.org/pkg/context#WithTimeout) to limit how long it can take.  Otherwise, you do not need to do anything special: just call `F1` with your context, and the rest will happen for you, no `select` is needed.